# Store images in directories and store a reference to the images in the database

Tags: php, mysql, image

I am currently involved in a project to create a website which allows users to share and rate images, for their creative media course.

I am trying to find ways to save images to a mysql database. I know i can save images as blobs, but this won't work as i plan on only allowing users to save high res images. Therefore, i've tried to find out how to store images in a directory/server folder and store references to the images in the database. An added complication to he matter, is that the reference must automatically save within a mysql database table.

Does anyone know how to go about this? or point me in the right direction?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've actually built a similar website (mass image uploader) so I can speak from experience.

### Keeping track of the files

Save the image file as-is on disk and save the path to the file in the database. This part should be pretty straightforward.

One disadvantage is that you need a database lookup for every image, but if your table is well optimized (indexes) this should be no real problem.

There are many advantages, such as your files become easily referable and you can add meta data to your files (like number of views).

### Filenames

Now, saving files, lots of files, is not immediately straightforward.

If you don't care at all about filenames just generate a random hash like:

```
$filename = md5(uniqid()); // generate a random hash, mileage may vary
```

This gets ride of all kind of filename related issues like duplicate filenames, unsupported characters etc.

If you want to preserve the filename, store the filename in the database.

If you want your filename on disk to also be somewhat human readable I would go for a mixed approach: partly hash, partly original filename. You will need to filter unsupported characters (like `/`), and perhaps transliterate similar characters (like `é -> e` and `ß -> ss`). Foreign languages such as Chinese and Hebrew can give *interesting* results, so be aware of that. You could also encode any foreign character (like base64_encode) but that doesn't do much for readability.

Finally, be aware of filepath length constraints. Filenames and filepaths can not be infinitely long. I believe Windows is 255 for the full path.

### Buckets

You should definitely consider using buckets because OSes (and humans) don't like folders with thousands of files.

If you're using hashes you already have a convenient bucket scheme available.

If your hash is `0aa1ea9a5a04b78d4581dd6d17742627`

Your bucket(s) can be: `0/a/a/1/e/a9a5a04b78d4581dd6d17742627`. In this case there are have 5 nested buckets. which means you can expect to have **one** file in each bucket after 16^5 (~1 million) files. How many levels of buckets you need is up to you.

### Mime-type

It's also good to keep track of the original file extension / mime-type. If you only have one kind of mime-type (like TIFF) then you don't need to worry about it. Most files have some way to easily detect that it's a file in that format but you don't want to have to rely on that. PNGs start with `PNG` (open one with a text editor to see it).

### Relative path vs absolute path

I would also recommend saving the relative path to the files, not the absolute path. This makes maintenance much easier.

So save:

```
0/a/a/1/e/a9a5a04b78d4581dd6d17742627
```

instead of:

```
/var/www/wwwdata/images/0/a/a/1/e/a9a5a04b78d4581dd6d17742627
```